# Consulta de trigger o disparador

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos, wordpress

Disculpen no soy experto en MySql y quisiera saber si es posible agregar datos de una tabla (Resultados ) a otra tablas (Datos) en la misma BD automáticamente sin php u otra lenguaje solamente con puras consultas de MySql.

La tabla "Resultados" tiene varias columnas la cual me importa el "ID" y solo quiero agarrarlo y ponerlo en el campos de la tabla "Datos" en la columna "ID_datos"
No tengo bien en claro como hacer esa inserción en el TRIGGER seleccionando las columnas.

```
CREATE TRIGGER traspaso
    AFTER INSERT
    ON resultados FOR EACH ROW datos
    INSERT INTO ID_datos
```

Tabla Resultados
[image: Tabla Resultados]

Tabla Datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sí, es perfectamente posible. Basta con programar un `TRIGGER`, el cual se disparará cuando la acción indicada ocurra en la tabla (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) y hará lo que programes en el TRIGGER (insertar en otra tabla u otra cosa). [Aquí te dejo un tutorial sobre `TRIGGER`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/). Los `TRIGGER` se programan en la BD directamente y listo, no tienes que preocuparte por nada más.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ahora mi duda es como seleccionar solo una columna y ponerlo en otra :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres insertar el nuevo `ID` de la tabla `resultados` en `ID_datos`, sería así:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `resultados_after_insert`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `resultados_after_insert` 
AFTER INSERT ON `resultados` 
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO `Datos` (`ID_datos`) VALUES(NEW.`ID`);
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

En los `TRIGGER` la clave es `NEW.` y `OLD.`, que sirven para referirte a los valores nuevos o antiguos, según la naturaleza del evento que ocurrió. Aquí usamos `NEW` porque, si ocurrió un `INSERT` (el tipo de `TRIGGER` es `AFTER INSERT`) se entiende que habrá una nueva fila con los nuevos datos insertados.

Comment: Muchas gracias padrino. te lo agradezco